# Oracle 11g migration to AWS

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, rman, dataguard

I have an on premise oracle 11g database that i have to migrate to an EC2 instance hosting Oracle 11g in AWS. I have three options to achieve this

1. Use Oracle Data guard to replicate the on premise database to cloud database
2. Using RMAN to backup the existing database and restore it on Cloud
3. Using expdp and impdp commands to export and import the database

My database size is approximately 2 TB.

I have following doubts

Q1: What is the best way among the three options?

Q2: Using data guard means that the AWS and the on premise database should be connected the entire time until the data is replicated on cloud, what if there is a network disconnect in between the process? Do i have to restart the replication process or will it continue from where it stopped?

Edit:
We have a 2 day downtime window in which the data has to be migrated and restored on cloud. The on premise database is hosted on Solaris Operating System and Operating System on the AWS cloud will be RedHat Linux since Solaris in not available in AWS.

Will Oracle Data guard or RMAN support the change in the Operating system on the servers?

Comment: The answer is: it depends. Can your database tolerate downtime? If not, then Data Guard is your best option (yes, it would continue where it left off in the event of an outage, assuming the necessary redo or archived redo is still available at the source). If so, then how much? RMAN is probably faster than datapump. Is the physical configuration (storage/directory locations, etc.) of the database in AWS the same as on-premise? This may affect the level of difficulty on the RMAN or datapump approaches if components need to be remapped.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @pmdba. I have added more details in the question

Comment: Is your Solaris Server Sparc ot Intel architecture?

Answer (score 0):

1: Data Guard between x86 Linux and SPARC Solaris will not work (unless it is x86 Solaris), see:

[Data Guard Support for Heterogeneous Primary and Physical Standbys in Same Data Guard Configuration (Doc ID 413484.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=413484.1)

2: Same for RMAN, due to the difference in endianness of these hardware platforms. Even if the on-premise system is x86 Solaris, restoring a backup on different platform with same endianness is not supported (restore actually works, but recovery does not). Oracle allows building the standby databases with RMAN active duplication instead of backups in such configuration.

3: That will work, you should be able to manage less than2 TB in 2 days with this.

Q1: Most likely Data Pump, unless your on-premise is x86 Solaris.

Q2: It can reconnect and continue where it was interrupted.